# Quasi-projective variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a simple question about definitions.  If X is a quasi-projective variety, then what does it mean for $U_i$ to be a cover by affine varieties?  If X lives in projective space, how can it have open sets in another space?  Thanks.

Comment: An affine variety is a variety which is isomorphic to a closed subset of affine space.

Comment: A variety in projective space can still be an affine variety.

Comment: Ok.  So the open sets are isomorphic to closed sets in some affine n space then?

Comment: Given $P^2=\{[x,y,z]\}$ the projective plane, the subspace defined by $\{z\ne 0\}=\{[x,y,1]\}$ is isomorphic to the affine plane.